# Check dimensions of the integral of a function

Tags: units, integration, dimensional-analysis, calculus

I and a colleague are arguing about the dimensions of:

$$\int_0^x f(x) dx $$

in this particular case $[f(x)]=m^2/s^3$ and $[x]=m$.

Does it follow that $[\int_0^x f(x) dx]=m^2/s^3$ or $[\int_0^x f(x) dx]=m^2/s^3m$?

Comment: $m^2/s^3m$ is more ambiguous than $m^3/s^3$. Also note $\displaystyle \int_0^x f(x) dx$ is not optimal either - is $x$ a variable or the limit of integration?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It will be the latter case, $m^2/s^3m$ which is just $m^3/s^3$.

Remember that the integral is the sum of all the **products** $f(x)\;\text{times}\; dx$. $dx$ is a tiny piece of the path from $0$ to $x$, so it is in units of $m$ as well. Each of the products $f(x)dx$ have units $m^3/s^3$, and the sum of all these products keeps those units.

Answer (score 8):

The dimensions of the integral are simply those of $f(x)dx$, so in this case they would be $m^2/s^3 \times m = m^3/s^3$.